# How can I view and easily delete pictures?

Tags: photos

Could you advise me of some way to view pictures and easily delete some of them when viewing (with one or two taps)?

I'm using Android 2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [QuickPic](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder).